# Ожидание в асинхронности

Tags: c#, async-await, tpl

Есть абстрактный пример:

```
async void Do() 
{
    ...
    await DownloadSomething();
    // какой-то другой код, который выполнится позже 
    ...
}

void FuncMain() 
{
    Do();
    //какой-то код
}
```

Когда начинается "долгая"  операция `DownloadSomething`, управление передаётся в `FuncMain`, а после, когда загрузка закончится, продолжается код после `DownloadSomething`. 
Вопрос: где удерживается `await DownloadSomething`? Или удерживается в каком-то потоке из пула?

Comment: [Смотрите](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lh8cT6qI-nA), [читайте](https://habrahabr.ru/post/216659/).

Comment: @andreycha спасибо за ссылки.

Comment: @andreycha почитал статью, понял самое главное, что мне требовалось, - имеется поток "посредник" iocp, который сигнализирует задаче о завершении операции. Из видео подчерпнул много интересных моментов. Благодарю ещё раз !

Comment: Верно. Важно помнить, что IOCP поток просто сообщает о том, что IO операция завершилась и что выполнение кода можно продолжить. И что один IOCP поток обрабатывает множество таких уведомлений за единицу времени. Но IOCP поток не "удерживает `await DownloadSomething`". Нет вообще никакого потока, который это "удерживает".

Comment: @andreycha да, в этом у меня и было недопонимание. Я знал, что никакой поток "не удерживает" операцию. Но никак не мог понять, как происходит оповещение о завершении операции; ведь прерывания на уровне пользовательского приложения запрещены, или я не прав - по поводу прерываний?

Comment: Нет, все правильно.

Comment: @khirnick вы немного не правы, прерывания существуют и разрешены. В *nix они называются сигналами, в windows - apc. Но суть их одна - в какой-то момент ядро вместо возобновления потока передает управление какому-то обработчику положив в стек адрес возврата. Точно так же как это делает процессор при прерываниях.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы вопрос не оставался без ответа:

Дело в том, что `async`-метод не является методом в обычном понимании этого слова. С точки зрения внешнего кода, его выполнение заканчивается практически сразу (с первым `await`'ом, который ожидает неокончившийся `Task`*).

На время ожидания метод *не выполняется нигде*. Это не буддистский коан, а реальная подробность имплементации `async`/`await`.

По существу `await` выполняется так: код просто подписывает на окончание выполнения `Task`'а метод специального скрытого объекта, и завершает выполнение. При окончании работы `Task`'а метод получает управление, и при помощи довольно простых трюков (наподобие `goto` в середину кода) возобновляет выполнение кода `async`-метода. Таким образом, во время `await`'а метод не выполняется ни в каком потоке.

---

*или tasklike

Answer (score 0):

Смотря, что стоит в DownloadSomething(). Если это IO то поток IO. который фиксирован и независим от приложения. DB, SQL, Download и т.д. в ту же копилку.
В момент передачи идут сохрание информации текущей конфигурации потока и как его возвращать. Текущий поток высвобождается и по окончанию происходит обратный вызов из пула нового/исходного потока. (ConfigureAwait(true/false)).